# NestJS Graphql webpack production build Error

Tags: node.js, webpack, graphql, nestjs

I am getting schema type error when I build my project with webpack in production. Error: "Error while boostrapping Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "s""

This only happens using production build and development build works fine.

This is my resolver:

```
@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

    @Query(() => User)
    public async getAll(@Parent() {id}): Promise<any> {
        return await this.userService.findUsers(id);
    }

    @Mutation(() => ResponseMessage)
    public async registerUser(@Args('registerUser') registerUser: RegisterUserInput): Promise<ResponseMessage> {
        return await this.userService.register(registerUser);
    }

    @Mutation(() => User)
    public async updateUser(@Args('updateUser') updateUser: UpdateUserInput): Promise<User> {
        return await this.userService.update(updateUser);
    }
}
```

removing the `@Mutation()` and only keeping `@Query` it compiles fine and the application gets built. I am using **autoSchemaFile** to generate the schema file.

Comment: fixed the issue by adding this in my webpack config   
```optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    namedModules: true,
    namedChunks: true,
    moduleIds: "named"
  },```

not minimizing the build solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blow code will be worked. I don't know why `minimize: true` not work for NestJS on production mode.

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false,  
},
```

Comment: i don't know too, but this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Production mode of webpack automatically enables minification. Be default, this changes class and function names. This is especially a problem for NestJS GraphQL schema if you are using that.

You can adjust the nestjs webpack minification configuration to use the [**TerserPlugin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser-webpack-plugin) to configure minification settings to preserve function and class names.

See the documentation [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions)

Here is an example of this implemented for NestJS in the `webpack.config.js` file.

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

...

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },

...
```